# upload csv file via postman to aws lambda and process

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am uploading csv file to lambda and set this to mapping template in API gateway but getting error when hitting the API.

`{ "content": "$input.body" }`

Error :

```
"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{\n    \"content\": \"test,testing\r\ntest1,test2\r\ntest3,test4\"\n}\"; line: 2, column: 30]"
```

could someone suggest what changes are required in the mapping for csv to be read?